# How to continiously check how many files are in a folder with AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, memory-leaks

So right now I am continiously sending xmlhttprequests with GET to a PHP script that is giving me back the amount of files in a folder.

I repeated the javascript function with a `setInterval()` and it is working really fine but I want the `setInteral()` to stop as soon as I get back a certain number from my PHP script.

Here's my code:

```
    <script>
    function checkmedia(url,format) {
      var format1 = format;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              progress = this.responseText;
                document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML =
                    this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", 'checkfilecount.php?userurl='+url+'&act=run&format-option=' + format, true);
        xhttp.send();
        if(progress != "100") {
        var media_progress = setInterval(checkmedia.bind(null,url,format1), 10000);
      }
    }
</script>
```

As I am calling this XMLHttpRequest continiously and several times (for a table) I am getting a memory leak.

Any kind of help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setInterval()` function repeatedly calls a function at a specified interval. The `setTimeout()` function calls a function *once* after a specified delay. You've used the wrong one...

You're getting a memory leak because you are calling `setInterval()` from *inside* the function, so every time it runs it spawns an additional interval, and then those spawn their own, etc., and nowhere do you clear the interval.

You could call `setInterval()` from outside the function, then modify your `if` to decide whether to call `clearInterval()` to stop the whole thing ([Blaze Sahlzen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42290247/615754) shows how to do that neatly), but I think it is much simpler to just use `setTimeout()` instead:

```
function checkmedia(url, format) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      progress = this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      if (progress != "100") {
        setTimeout(checkmedia.bind(null, url, format), 10000);
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", 'checkfilecount.php?userurl=' + url + '&act=run&format-option=' + format, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

You'd want to add some code to handle Ajax errors, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I think this is a better approach because `setInterval` won't wait for the previous instance to complete processing if it takes too long, and we could have multiple instances running, causing memory leak again. Is this a likely scenario?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen - Well obviously the `setTimeout()` version guarantees a maximum of one ajax call at a time, so I guess that's safer, though I just realised I oversimplified a bit because I should've because I should've put the `if` in the `onreadstatechange` handler (which I'll do now), and also I should've allowed for ajax errors (which I can't be bothered doing). At least `setInterval()` will keep polling even if errors occur.

Comment: I used the code in this answer and it works perfectly! Thank you. Nontheless both answers were very helpful and I learned alot from both of them. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way in which you can approach this situation:

```
function check(url, format) {

  function checkmedia(url, format) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = this.responseText;

        if (Number(this.responseText) === 100) {
          clearInterval(media_progress);
        }
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", 'checkfilecount.php?userurl=' + url + '&act=run&format-option=' + format, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }

  var media_progress = setInterval(checkmedia.bind(null, url, format), 10000);
}

check('your_url', 'your_format');
```

Using `clearInterval` you can stop `setInterval` function when you've reached a particular condition.

Comment: Nice work. You saved me from having to write this technique up in my own answer, I just linked to yours instead.

Comment: Thanks! But you still beat me to the answer though :p @nnnnnn

Comment: Oh well. If I had taken the time to write both variations up front you might have been first, but I figured the `setTimeout()` version was easier so that's what I went with.